# Como optimizar o Firebird 3?

Tags: delphi, firebird

Alguém que trabalha com Firebird 3, sabe o que exatamente como optimizar o SGDB para ser mais eficiente? Até agora fiz alguns testes com o Firebird 2.5 e o 3 para comparar consultas, e basicamente continua mesma coisa.

**Update**
Percebi que optimização da versão 2.5 para 3.0 foi mais na questão de bancos remotos, onde há uma compressão.

Answer (score 2):

Existem algumas regras genéricas e básicas para o melhor desempenho do banco de dados, [aqui](https://ib-aid.com/en/articles/45-ways-to-speed-up-firebird-database/) você pode conferir elas, especificamente da 37 em diante para o FireBird.
Logo:

- Use conexões em pool se forem pequenas e rápidas
- Usar o [Linger](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/community/conference-2014/pdf/02_fb.2014.whatsnew.30.en.pdf) no Firebird 3
- Usar JOIN com Hash
- Marcar funções[determinísticas](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions)
- Usar funções analíticas
- Não usar autenticação SRP caso não seja necessário
- Preferir a chamada de funções ao invés de [UDF's](https://www.firebirdsql.org/pdfmanual/html/ufb-cs-embedded.html)

Answer (score 0):

Tem uma [lista](http://www.firebase.com.br/artigo.php?id=2920) de dicas de desempenho para o banco de dados Firebird, em diferentes áreas - desde hardware/sistema operacional, tuning da configuração do Firebird até recomendações de otimização de SQL. Esta [lista](http://www.firebase.com.br/artigo.php?id=2920) não é uma referência completa de como otimizar o Firebird, e assume que você tenha noções básicas do funcionamento do SGBD, como planos de execução, gerenciamento de transações e estatísticas de desempenho das consultas.

Essas dicas estão no site http://www.firebase.com.br/artigo.php?id=2920

Comment: Veja lá nesse site tem muita coisa que você pode aprender para melhor a performasse do FB.